# How do I remove my toilet seat?

Tags: toilet, screws

I want to install a Japanese washlet but I can't remove the toilet seat cover. The picture below is the screw underneath, and I think there are no hidden fixings.

[image: picture of the screw]

Comment: Thanks for providing a picture so many fail to do that. Would you please [edit] your question to provide a _focused_ picture. It's _really_ hard to tell what we're looking at here beyond "something blurry".

Comment: AFIK there is always a pair of slotted head screws each under a snap up flap visible with the toilet cover down. If the screws are plastic the slots in the screws will be well fitted by a very large screwdriver, but a smaller screwdriver will usually work. Some of these screws are plastic and some are stainless steel. The steel screws will have a smaller slot. Reach under with your hand and hold the nut in your fingers to prevent the nut from spinning while you turn the screwdriver from the top.

Comment: I have seen unslotted heads.

Answer (score 9):

If there is a screw slot at the top (may be under a snap-off cover) you can turn that. Otherwise, that black thing is basically a nut, and you can turn that to remove it.

Comment: Yeah, that nut doesn't look like it's intended to be manipulated from below. Find the other end.

Answer (score 9):

That's basically a conical nut that squeezes a split pin apart as it's tightened *from above*.
There must be a corresponding screw/bolt head on the top side, probably behind a snap-on cap.

That looks like a great way to break the porcelain, btw, maximum tension for minimum effort.